# jquery form validation plugin add class to the input when error occurs

Tags: jquery

I have designed a form with jquery validation plugin. I wanted to change the input border color when the error message occurs.

```js
 $("#commentForm").validate({
  rules: {
     user: {
        required:true
     },
     mail: {
        required: true,
        email: true
     },
     secret: {
        required:true,
        minlength:6,
        maxlength:6
     },
     mobile: {
        digits:true,
        required:true,
        minlength:10,
        maxlength:10
     },
     address: {
        required:true,
        url:true
     },
     'choose': {
        required:true
     }
  },

 //message//

  messages: {
     user: "Please enter your name",
     mail: "Please enter your email",
     secret: "Enter password with min & max length of 6",
     mobile: "Enter mobile number in number format",
     address: "Enter mobile number in number format",
     choose: "Please select your Age"
  }
 });
```

```css
.panel-body{
 background-color:rgba(0,0,128,0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="margin-top:10px">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
       <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading text-center">
             <h3>Jquery Form Validation</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
             <form  id="commentForm" name=""  class="form-horizontal" id="Vform" method="POST" action="trail.html" >
                <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                   <label class="col-sm-4" for="user">Username*</label>
                   <input class="col-sm-8" name="user" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                   <label class="col-sm-4" for="secret">Password</label>
                   <input class="col-sm-8" name="secret" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Password">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                   <label class="col-sm-4" for="mobile">Mobile*</label>
                   <input class="col-sm-8" name="mobile" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Mobile Number">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                   <label class="col-sm-4" for="mail">Email</label>
                   <input class="col-sm-8" name="mail" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Email" >
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                   <label class="col-sm-4" for="address">Url</label>
                   <input class="col-sm-8" name="address" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                   <label class="col-sm-4" for="choose">Age</label>
                   <select class="col-sm-8" name="choose" style="padding: 4px;" class="form-control">
                      <option value="" >Choose</option>
                      <option value="Above18">Above 18</option>
                      <option value="Below18">Below 18</option>
                   </select>
                </div>
                <!--submit button-->
                <div>
                   <center><button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" >SUBMIT</button></center>
                </div>
             </form>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I figured out that I should add a class for that but I don't know how to code. I'm completely new to jquery. Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: [STO](https://stackoverflow.com) is not a free code site.Write your code get an error share your error with us, then everybody helps you !

Comment: If you are completely new to jquery....First try to cover documention of jquery then start coding.....that would be more helpfull in future...don't search required and copy paste.

Comment: Actually, you got me wrong I never used jquery validation plugin. The code above was written on my own. I just don't get it how to add class when error message occurs

Comment: If the user input is empty the error message "Please enter your name" will be visible below the input field. My question is the time the error message pops up the input border color should change.

Comment: I've moved the code into a snippet, check and fix it where required. I know it can be done, seen it before, but I've no idea how to fix it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Validate default use the following rules for an element. `.error` for error and `.valid` for valid value.

```
.error {
    border: 2px solid #f00;
}

.valid {
    border: 2px solid #0ff;
}
```